# style display hidden and accessibility form, appropriate or not?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

Suppose I have a DB of users and I have two main functions: to view or edit existing users.

A page will display a user using `dl` for example:

```
 <h1>Information</h1>
 <dl>
      <dt>Name:</dt>
      <dd>
        xyz
      </dd>
      <dt>Phone Number:</dt>
      <dd>
        (123)-424-2345
      </dd>
      <dt>Hobby:</dt>
      <dd>
        Fishing
      </dd>
</dl>
```

There will also *on the same page* be a form to edit the existing information, for example:

```
<form action="#">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Information</legend>

    <label>Name:</label><input type="text" name="name" />
    <label>Phone Number:</label><input type="text" name="phoneNumber" />
    <label>Hobby:</label>
    <select>
        <option value="1">Coding</option>
        <option value="2" selected="selected">Fishing</option>
        <option value="3">Reading</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

So, in the body of the HTML document both of these sections will be present within its own division (`div`).  Which will be rendered to display in the browser will be determined client-side through JavaScript and use of the CSS `display` style setting the appropriate section to not display (be hidden).

AJAX, a popular thing these days, will reload each section after the form is submitted.

The end goal being that only one is present at a time to the user (either they view existing, or are able to toggle on the ability to edit, once editing is finished AJAX reloads and the view mode is restored to view and the form is hidden again).

So from HTML5 and accessibility point-of-view, is this type of thing common and acceptable?  Or is it better to make AJAX change the contents of the div between the view and edit (e.g. more AJAX calls)?  Or is there some other better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better to go for ajax. Since it is mostly form elements, hope there is nothing interesting for a search crawler (SEO point of view).

"display:none" make the content inaccessible to screen readers. So there is an accessibility issue when using hidden elements. Page will be heavier if we use so many hidden elements in one page.

The benefit of using hidden elements is the user will get the sections more quickly. We can avoid more server pings & avoid storing data before submitting (if any).

Answer (score 0):

It is a potential risk. Somebody would be able to use any modern browser to make the form viewable by editing it's css property and would then be able to submit the form.

If you're using AJAX, why not use one `<div>` element which shows the view in view mode, and then when the form is requested the html will be written into the div from the AJAX request. After submitting or closing the form, the AJAX call would then write the new View mode back into the div.

This way you can ensure that only users with the right permissions are able to see the form since the form will not still exist in the html unless served by you under the right circumstances.

Comment: That's true, but you can also check (and should) the user permissions on the server side in the script that is submitted to.  Further, if they are not a user able to edit I would just not write the hidden form html part in.  The hidden thing is meant for already qualified users to switch between modes quickly.